# Towers of Hanoi alphabetical rings

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out a little twist on the Towers of Hanoi puzzle.

I have the Towers of Hanoi puzzle algorithm figured out, however, my goal is to instead of using numbers for for the rings, I am to use letters up to 26 (A..Z).

I am also tasked with calling the puzzle using only an int parameter:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 

    MyTools.moveDisks(3);


}
```

}

Instead of the normal TOH method which would use (int, char, char, char) parameters.

This is what I've come up with:

```
    public static int count = 0;
public static char fromTow = 'A';
public static char toTow = 'B';
public static char tempTow = 'C';
public static char[] disks = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
        'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };



public static void towersOfHanoi (int n, char fromTow, char toTow, char tempTow, char disks[]) {

    count++;    

    if (n == 1) {
    System.out.println("Move disk 1 from " + fromTow + " to " + toTow);

    } else {
        towersOfHanoi(n - 1, fromTow, tempTow, toTow, disks);
    System.out.println("Move disk " + disks[n-1] + " from " + fromTow + " to " + toTow);

        towersOfHanoi(n - 1, tempTow, toTow, fromTow, disks);
    }

}

public static void moveDisks (int n) {
    count++;
    System.out.println("List of the moves for " + n + " disks:");

        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println("Move disk a from " + fromTow + " to " + toTow);

        } else {
            towersOfHanoi(n-1, fromTow, tempTow, toTow, disks);
            System.out.println("Move disk " + disks[n-1] + " from " + fromTow + " to " + toTow);

            towersOfHanoi(n - 1, tempTow, toTow, fromTow, disks);

        System.out.println("The total number of moves is: " + count);



        }

    }

}
```

Calling it with Mytools.moveDisks(3) gives me this output:

List of the moves for 3 disks:

Move disk 1 from A to B

Move disk b from A to C

Move disk 1 from B to C

Move disk c from A to B

Move disk 1 from C to A

Move disk b from C to B

Move disk 1 from A to B

The total number of moves is: 7

So everything works except the disk letters. I tried creating a char array holding all the letters, but cannot figure how to correctly implement them into the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the first If-statement in the `towersOfHanoi(...)`. You put the static string as:

> "Move disk ***1*** from " + fromTow + " to " + toTow

Also, a more convenient way of printing the character in correspondance to *n* is:

```
(char) 96 + n
```

This will be computed as

> a,b,c,... for n = 1,2,3,...